# Help needed with woocommerce (wc stripe) filter

Tags: plugins, filters, woocommerce-offtopic, actions

WC Stripe has an option where you can set it to 'capture immediately' or leave it unchecked for authorize payment only. I have left it checked by default, but there is a specific product category, where I dont want "Capture Immediately". How can I dynammically turn that off at the time of checkout with specific product with category in cart. I originally asked WooCommerce support but their response was a little over my knowledge over php and wordpress. I really appreciate all the help.

[image]

Response from WooCommerce Support

> All settings of the Stripe plugin are filtered. Have a look at: **/includes/settings-stripe.php** - maybe you can leverage this.
>
> Other than that take a look **capture_payment()** and how its hooked. You could try and add a conditional that unhooks this for your desired category.

URLs to the references:

> [/includes/settings-stripe.php](https://gist.github.com/uakhan/59abdcaddf21770b12cb537b8c052c93)
>
> [function: capture_payment()](https://gist.github.com/uakhan/59abdcaddf21770b12cb537b8c052c93)

Answer (score 0):

in filtering one of the meta, you can stop capture depending of the order content

```
add_filter("get_post_metadata", function ($value, $object_id, $meta_key, $single) {


    if ("_stripe_charge_id" === $meta_key) {

        $order = wc_get_order($object_id);


        if (???) {
            // stop capture
            $value = FALSE;
        }

    }


    return $value;

}, 10, 4);
```

Comment: Thank you! 
So I replace "if (???) {" with "if ( is_product() && has_term( 'Custom', 'product_cat' ) ) {" ?

Comment: MMM, sorry I am still an amateur, can you please help with the full code, if possible? Payment for any product having category "custom" should not be captured.